How to find the summation of this following series.
Q) How to find the summation of the series in a shortcut method:
$\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{7}i}+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=2}^{8}i}+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=3}^{9}i}+...+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=22}^{28}i}$
I know how to find the summations of series's like:
$1)\frac{1}{1×2}+\frac{1}{2×3}+\frac{1}{3×4}+...+\frac{1}{27×28}$
$2)\frac{1}{1×2×3}+\frac{1}{2×3×4}+\frac{1}{3×4×5}+...+\frac{1}{26×27×28}$
The summations of these above two series's can be found very easily.
The answer to the summation of $1^{st}$ series is $\frac{27}{28}$.
And the second series will be like:
$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1×2}-\frac{1}{2×3}+\frac{1}{2×3}-\frac{1}{3×4}+\frac{1}{3×4}-\frac{1}{4×5}+...+\frac{1}{26×27}-\frac{1}{27×28})$.
Now the summation of the $2^{nd}$ series is easy to find after this step.
The problem arises mainly for the sequences like:
$3)\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{4}i}+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=2}^{5}i}+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=3}^{6}i}+...+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=25}^{28}i}$
$4)\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{5}i}+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=2}^{6}i}+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=3}^{7}i}+...+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=24}^{28}i}$
$5)\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{6}i}+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=2}^{7}i}+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=3}^{8}i}+...+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=23}^{28}i}$
And so on.
The calculation goes bigger and bigger for these three series's.
This question came in my mind while I was studying the chapter Sequences and Series.
I also asked this question to the teachers of my coaching institute. But no one has cleared my doubt.
Please help me out with evaluating the summation of this series.
The main thing which I want is a shortcut to these types of summations.

Hint: Do the same, find a telescoping series (instead of trying to partial fractions it). Hopefully this should be obvious, esp as you try it for your 1st series, and also the 3rd unstated series (where the denominator has 3 terms)

Ok. Thank you @CalvinLin

A standard notation for these kinds of products is the Pochhammer symbol (or falling/rising factorial).

In your expression
$$
\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{6}i}+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=2}^{7}i}+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=3}^{8}i}+...+\frac{1}{\prod_{i=23}^{28}i}
$$
the summands are
\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac 1 {\prod_{k=n}^{n+d} i}=\frac 1{(n)_{d+1}}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n+d)!}
\\ &
=\frac1d\left[\frac{(n-1)!}{((n-1)+d)!}-\frac{n!}{(n+d)!}\right]=\frac1d[b_{n-1}-b_{n}]
\end{align}
where
$
b_n=\frac{n!}{(n+d)!}.
$
So
\begin{align}
S_p&=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac 1 {\prod_{k=n}^{n+d} i}= \sum_{n=1}^p  a_n=
\frac{b_0-b_1+b_1-b_2+\dots+b_{p-1}-b_p}{d}
\\ &=\frac{b_0-b_p}d=\frac 1 d \Bigg( \frac{1}{d!}-\frac{p!}{(d+p)!}\Bigg).
\end{align}
For your last case, use $d=5$ and $p=23$.

It helps to write the summation in another way. This reveals a simple pattern.
$\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k\cdot (k+1)}=1-\frac{1}{(N+1)}$
$\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k\cdot (k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1/2}{(N+1)(N+2)}$
$\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k\cdot (k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}=\frac{1}{18}-\frac{1/3}{(N+1)(N+2)(N+3)}$
$\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k\cdot (k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)}=\frac{1}{96}-\frac{1/4}{(N+1)(N+2)(N+3)(N+4)}$
$\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k\cdot (k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)(k+5)}=\frac{1}{600}-\frac{1/5}{(N+1)(N+2)(N+3)(N+4)(N+5)}$
The numbers 1, 4, 18, 96, 600, 4320, 35280, 322560 etc. can be found by the recursive relation:
$a_{n}=a_{n-1}\cdot \frac{n^2}{n-1}$ with $a_1=1$
